# Iterate Generic type<User> of ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to get the values from an arraylist.

I have the User type bean class as below..

```
class User{

      public String link;
      public String url;

     User(String l,String u){
           this.link=link;
           this.url=url;
      }
setters and getters below..
```

Here I am trying to write a class with main.

```
public class ListClass{
      public static void main(String args[]){
            List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
            list.add(new User("link1","url1"));
            list.add(new User("link2","url2"));
            list.add(new User("link3","url3"));

            //here i want to iterate both links and urls one by one 

            Iterator it=list.iterator();
            // remaining the code to get both link1 and url1 ..
}
```

I need the output as:

```
link1  url1
link2  url2
link3  url2
```

Comment: `this.l` should be `this.link`, ditto for `u` and `url`.

Comment: Constructor for "User" contains wrong assignment. And Using Iterator is a basic thing. Make a google search for examples on iterator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the for-in construct instead of the Iterator:

```
for (User u : list) {
  System.out.println(u.link + " " + u.url);
}
```

If you definitely want to use the iterator:

```
Iterator<User> it=list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  User u = it.next();
  System.out.println(u.link + " " + u.url);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As has already been stated by other users you can use the [enhanced `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2). Consider also adding a `toString()` implementation for `User`:

```
class User
{
    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return this.link + " " + this.url;
    }
}
```

which would reduce the loop to:

```
for (User u: list)
{
    System.out.println(u);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (User u : list) {
   System.out.println(u.getLink() + "  " + u.getUrl());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you insist with itereator:

```
Iterator<User> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
   /...
   it.next();
}
```